# Dealing with legacy database in Ruby on Rails causes weird class-loading issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, legacy

Short version: In trying to deal with a legacy database in Ruby-on-Rails, I've come across some class-loading behavior that I don't understand.

Long version: At my job, I'm working on a PHP codebase running against a MySQL database with sometimes-helpful, but usually-frustrating naming conventions.  So, it doesn't fit into the typical Ruby on Rails naming patterns.  An example:

```
create table objectOfSomeType (
    OOSTid int primary key auto_increment,
    OOSTatooID int,
    OOSTname varchar(255) not null,
    OOSTotherThing datetime,
    OOSTenteredDate timestamp not null,
    OOSTenteredBy varchar(32) not null,
    OOSTmodifiedDate timestamp,
    OOSTmodifiedBy varchar(32)
    /* etc. */
);

create table another_type_of_object (
    ATOOid int primary key auto_increment,
    ATOOname varchar(255) not null
    /* etc. */
);
```

Notable properties:

- objectOfSomeType - table name is singular, sometimes camelCased, sometimes under_scored
- OOST (Object Of Some Type) - columns all have a shared prefix
- OOSTid - virtually all tables have an auto-increment primary key = prefix + 'id'
- OOSTatooID - indicates a foreign key relationship against the anotherTypeOfObject table (which has prefix = 'ATOO')
- OOST{entered,modified}Date - correspond to RoR's {created,updated}_at

I tried to set up a subclass of `ActiveRecord::Base` that had some functions for dealing with the table prefixes.  E.g.:

```
class ActiveRecordJob < ActiveRecord::Base
    class_inheritable_accessor :table_prefix

    class << self
        # this class needs no table
        abstract_class = true

        # function to setup the prefix
        def set_table_prefix(prefix)
            self.table_prefix = prefix
            set_primary_key "#{prefix}id"
        end

        # override the standard column_names to return prefix-less names
        def column_names
            names = super
            if pfx = self.table_prefix
                # obviously not a Rubist...
                names = names.map { |n| n.sub(%r|^#{pfx}|, "") }
            end
            names
        end
    end

    # override method_missing to set up non-prefixed versions
    # if the prefixed version is found, otherwise fall back to super
    def method_missing(method, *args)
        if pfx = self.table_prefix
            prefixed = pfx + method
            if respond_to?(prefixed)
                self.class.send(:define_method, method.to_sym) do
                    return send(prefixed, *args)
                end
                return send(method, *args)
            end
        end
        super
    end
end

class ObjectOfSomeType < ActiveRecordJob
    set_table_name :objectOfSomeType
    set_table_prefix :OOST
    belongs_to :atoo, :class_name => 'AnotherTypeOfObject', :foreign_key => 'OOSTatooID'
end

class AnotherTypeOfObject < ActiveRecordJob
    set_table_name :anotherTypeOfObject
    set_table_prefix :ATOO
end
```

This works well enough for single models (an `ObjectOfSomeType` object has `name` and `otherProperty` attributes).  But, something is going wrong with the associations.  By way of example, in the object_of_some_type/show.html.erb template:

```
This works fine, no need for .OOSTname:
<%= h @oost.name %>

This works fine, accessing the prefixed name directly:
<%= h @oost.atoo.ATOOname %>

But this throws an exception, because the custom method_missing is not hit:
<%= h @oost.atoo.name %>

Surprisingly (to this Ruby noob), this does work.
<%= h @oost.atoo.class.find(@oost.atoo.id).name %> <!-- this line marked -->

After the above, working call, this also works:
<%= h @oost.atoo.name %>
```

What does the marked line do that "fixes" the problem?  I'm likely going to go a different route (setting up a database full of RoR-named views against this database), but I'd still like to fill in this gap in my Ruby knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveRecord is quite opinionated when it comes to naming conventions. You might have considerably more luck using DataMapper, which allows you to set up a model that uses its own Rails-like naming conventions for its attributes, but on save or update they are translated into their underlying column names in the database.

http://datamapper.org/docs/legacy